# Spring Batch: Listener event when Tasklet throws an exception

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using a tasklet and a `StepExecutionListener` but it seems there's no listener callback for a case where my tasklet throws an exception. For various other listener types – `ChunkListener`, `ItemProcessListener`, etc. – there is but none of those listeners work with tasklets.

All I want is an event after my tasklet executes regardless of whether it threw an exception or not. Is it possible to do that? It doesn't appear to be supported in the API.

Edit: Responding to @danidemi I'm registering the listener and tasklet using the programmatic API like this:

```
steps.get(name)
     .listener(listener)
     .tasklet(tasklet)
     .build()
```

Where `steps` is an instance of `StepBuilderFactory`.

Comment: Why does the `StepExecutionListener` work for your use case?

Comment: May I ask you how you registered the StepExecutionListener to the Tasklet ?

Comment: @danidemi I register it like this:

    steps.get(name)
         .listener(listener)
         .tasklet(tasklet)
         .build()

Comment: argh, sorry. Looks like markdown not supported in comments. I'll add to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can

1. manage exception into tasklet
2. store error into execution-context/external bean
3. manage error from stepExecutionListener

or in `StepExecutionListener.afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` lookup into [`stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#getFailureExceptions--)

Comment: I guess so. The problem is then you are forced to use a flow or a decider downstream if you want the exception to stop the job.

Answer (score -1):

I guess its too late now. But I recently came across this problem. It is easier to handle exception with ChunkListener, however exception handling can be done in Tasklet's `RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution s, ChunkContext chunkContext)` method (well, it is the only method that `Tasklet` interface has ^^). What you need is a `try/catch` block to catch the exceptions. However you will need to `throw` the caught exception again in order to roll back the transaction. 
Here is a code-snippet. In my case, I had to stop the job if some data could not be read due to Database server shutdown.

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution s, ChunkContext chunkContext){
    try{
        getAllUsersFromDb(); // some operation that could throw an exception
        // doesn't hurt to put all suspicious codes in this block tbh
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(e instanceof NonSkippableReadException){
            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().stop();
        }
        throw e;
    }
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is adding unnecessary complexity and it's error prone, because you need to remember to surround your code with a try / catch block for every step