# How to set ExceptionHandler in a Step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Here is the situation:

1. This is the job I defined in xml:

   ```
   <job id="readMultiFileJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
       <step id="step1" next="deleteDir">
           <tasklet>
               <chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
                   commit-interval="1" />
           </tasklet>
       </step>
       <step id="deleteDir">
           <tasklet ref="fileDeletingTasklet">
           </tasklet>
       </step>
   </job>
   ```
2. As you see, the job has two steps. In step 2 (`deleteDir`), I want to configure an `ExceptionHandler` into tasklet (`fileDeletingTasklet`) or step (`deleteDir`) so that I can handle all the exceptions in this step. For example, once project meet error in this step, I want to judge the exception type and send out an email to user.

Checking Spring Batch documentation, I just found this case:

```
SimpleStepFactoryBean<String, String> factory = getStepFactory(new String[] { "foo", "bar", "spam" });
        factory.setBeanName("exceptionStep");
        SimpleLimitExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new SimpleLimitExceptionHandler(1);
        exceptionHandler.afterPropertiesSet();
        factory.setExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
```

This case is not what I want. I defined step in xml and it's not easy to do configuration.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch: Listener event when Tasklet throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789712/spring-batch-listener-event-when-tasklet-throws-an-exception)